# Scripting Gnome Image Viewer in a dual screen setup

Tags: eog

I am attempting to use the eye of gnome command to open two instances of the image viewer on two separate displays. Trouble is, if I use the command:

```
eog -s --display=DVI-0 image.jpg
```

it states it cannot open the display (my assumption is that it is referring to X-displays). Is there a way to have one instance open on each screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is two problems here:

1. having two separate instances (or at least windows) of eog
2. controlling on which screen they open

The first one is simple : option `--new-instance` do the trick.

The scond one is more complicated. The --display argument refers to the *X server* to use, not the name of the screen and/or monitor (xorg.conf terminology). So --display is not the right think to use.

When issuing `eog --fullscreen image.jpg` on a terminal, the image open on the same screen than the terminal. So I suppose there is a way to tell Gtk to opens on a precise screen. (NB: option -s is for slideshow, i;e. if you want one single image, prefer fullscreen.)

From the documentation of GTK/Gdk, and the source code of eog, It seems that eog create a popup with teh image, and request gdk to set it fullscreen. Gdk then requests the window manager to set the "window" of the popup fullscreen. So the decision to open the image on this or that screen belongs to the window manager.

`wmctrl` seem to be the right tool to communicate with the window manager. Here is a draft of a script doing that.

```
#!/bin/bash
#open two fullscreen windows
eog --fullscreen --new-instance image1.jpg&
#wait until windows are actually created
while [ 1 ]; do 
   found=$(wmctrl -l |grep 'image1.jpg'); 
   if ! [[ -z "$found" ]]; then 
      break; 
   fi; 
done;
#move first win to the left
wmctrl -r 'image1.jpg' -e 1,0,0,-1,-1

eog --fullscreen --new-instance image2.jpg&
#wait
while [ 1 ]; do 
   found=$(wmctrl -l |grep 'image2.jpg'); 
   if ! [[ -z "$found" ]]; then 
      break; 
   fi; 
done;
#move
wmctrl -r 'image2.jpg' -e 1,1280,0,-1,-1
```

But you should replace 1280 with your actual screen width. Also note that, because the script use window names to identify them, this will not work if windows with similar names ('image1', 'image2') exists on your desktop.

Comment: They still open up on top of each other when I use this method. Perhaps I need to adjust the numbers?

Comment: It looks like this method is moving the windows within the display 'selected' by the terminal?

Comment: It suceeded here with `sleep 1s` before each wmctrl command. I think because the window is not yet created when the wmctrl command is executed. I will update my answer.

Comment: The edited version doesn't seem to work either. If I execute it from the right screen it will work for a moment but then move over to the left. I did notice that if I set the width to two times my actual width it will open in a lower workspace (one that is unseen unless I manually switch to it)

Comment: another fix... dumb confusion between x and y coordinates... But other things, like focus, desktop environments, and so on may be interfering too...

Comment: Oops, I might have caught that if I had bothered reversing those when I was trying different things. Do you think it would work ok if it were automatically called at startup?

Comment: I think it is possible to run this in your session startup. but if you intend to use this as a kind of wallpaper, I'm affrad eog is not the good tool.

Comment: It's just for a multi-panel display that needs to run through images in a file. It's convenient since a new image would be reflected in the slideshow automatically (after it is set to slideshow mode of course) Thanks for the help!